# How to get id of the clicked element from the child to the parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have one Parent and one child component.
In child i have notes inner elements ,where delete is one of them.

**I need upon clicking delete element in child component it should return an ID to the parent element , so that it should be identified to which array element it clicked.**

**Parent**

```js
const Main = () => {

    const notes = [
        {id:1,
         title:"What is React? ",
        content:"React is a JavaScript library that aims to simplify development of visual interfaces.",
        // date:"28/04/2023"
        },
        {
         id:2,
         title:"What is Java?",
         content:"Java is a most popular, object-oriented, widely used programming language and platform that is utilized for Android development, web development, artificial intelligence, cloud applications, and much more.",
        //  date:"28/04/2023"
        }
    ]
    const [mynote, setNote] = useState(notes);
    const [isActive,setisActive] = useState([]);
    
     const navActive = () =>{
       setisNav(curr => !curr);
      }
  

  return (
    <div className='main'>

     <div className={`leftnote`}>
        
     <div className={`notesdiv`}>
      <div className={`notes`} >
      { 
        mynote.map((obj)=>{
            return( <div  key={obj.id}  onClick={() => handleClick(obj.id)} className={`notes ${isActive === obj.id ? 'active':'inactive'}`}>
            <Notes notetitle = {obj.title} notedate={obj.date} />
            </div>    
            )
        })     
      } 
      </div> 
      </div> 

     </div>
     
     </div>
   }
```

**Child**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Notes.css';
import note from './images/note.png';
import del from './images/delete.png';


const Notes = ({notetitle,notedate}) => {
   
  return (
      <div className="note">
      <div className="div1">
      <div className="noteimg">
        <img src={note} alt="note" />
      </div>
       <div className="notemain">
           <h2>{notetitle}</h2>
           <h3>{notedate}</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div className="div2">
    <div className="delimg">
        <img src={del} alt="delete" />
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Notes
```

Please help me with the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you can pass the function as a prop to the child. So, your function with logic to delete or any other action with the `id` of child should be defined in the parent component and should be passed to the child as a prop which will be called from the child component.